# ТЛ на одном тесте

Tags: c++, сортировка

Доброго времени суток! Решал задачу, условие прилагается. Проблема в том, что на одном тесте выдает ошибку времени (ограничение в полсекунды). Ускорение ввода проблему не решило. Вопрос: есть ли у меня подводный камень в коде, или возможна ошибка в тестах? Заранее спасибо

**EDIT :** файлы действительно те, в пдф условии неправильно указано про станд. ввод/вывод

Код таков :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long n, m;

    ifstream fin ("input.txt");    //   FILES
    ofstream fout ("output.txt"); // ASSIGNMENTS

    // INPUT //
    fin >> n; // Quantity of required decks
    long requiredDecks[n]; // Array of required decks for the tricks
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fin >> requiredDecks[i];

    fin >> m; // Quantity of decks in stock
    long checker[100] = {0}; // Array of existence of all possible decks in stock
    for (long i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        long deck;
        fin >> deck;
        checker[deck]++;
    }

    // END OF INPUT //

    // MAIN PART OF PROGRAM //
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (checker[requiredDecks[i]] < 1) { // Checking for non-existence of concrete deck in hands
            fout << "NO" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else
            --checker[requiredDecks[i]];

    // END OF MAIN PART //
    fout << "YES" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Скрин с условием]

Comment: @Niklex https://ideone.com/lsnwKs пробуйте.

Comment: @pavel, жаль, но не зашла :( Очевидно, тестики кривые. Спасибо за время :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67656/discussion-on-question-by-niklex----).

Answer (score 3):

хранить все миллионы чисел не нужно. Нужно просто составить список, сколько карт и каких есть и просто потом сравнить два списка. Я минимально пофиксил, но чуточку исправил. Ну не давать же полный ответ.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long n, m;


    // INPUT //
    cin >> n; // Quantity of required decks
    long requiredDecks[56] = {0}; // Array of required decks for the tricks
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        long t;
        cin >> t;
        requiredDecks[t-1]++;
    }

    cin >> m; // Quantity of decks in stock
    long checker[56] = {0}; // Array of existence of all possible decks in stock
    for (long i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        long deck;
        cin >> deck;
        checker[deck-1]++;
    }

    // END OF INPUT //

    // MAIN PART OF PROGRAM //
    for (long i = 0; i < 56; i++)
        if (checker[i] < requiredDecks[i]) {
            cout << "NO" << endl;
            return 0;
        }

    // END OF MAIN PART //
    cout << "YES" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спорим не пройдёт?)

Comment: @KoVadim, хорошая идея, мне в голову не пришла. Но зная эту систему.. Ща проверю, момент

Comment: @KoVadim, не прошло. Вы знаете, я сейчас даже просто отправил прогу, которая просто считывает, она тоже не зашла. Рискну, все - таки, придположить, что это тесты кривые :) Но все равно спасибо

Comment: @pavel, тоже спасибо за участие

Comment: @Niklex 10 минут подожди.

Comment: @Niklex, ну используй наконец scanf и int вместо cin и long.

Comment: отключаем sync_with_stdio и наслаждаемся

Comment: @Qwertiy, ахах, не привык еще. Но оно не имеет значение. Я ускорляку ставил. Думаю, тесты

Comment: @KoVadim, двано еще поставил. Вместо с cin.tie(). Гадость...